# Coderbyte Challenge: Questions Marks

Tags: javascript

Have the function QuestionsMarks(str) take the str string parameter, which will contain single digit numbers, letters, and question marks, and check if there are exactly 3 question marks between every pair of two numbers that add up to 10. If so, then your program should return the string true, otherwise it should return the string false. If there aren't any two numbers that add up to 10 in the string, then your program should return false as well.

My solution:

```
function QuestionsMarks(str) { 
    result = false;

    for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
       
        for(let j = i+1; j < str.length; j++){
         
            if(Number(str[i]) + Number(str[j]) === 10){              
                result = true;
             
                if(str.slice(i, j).split("?").length -1 != 3){
                  return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Apparently for the Codebyte it isn't correct answers as it returns false for the following strings

```
"9???1???9???1???9"

"5??aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa?5?a??5"
```

But if description says `"exactly 3 question marks between every pair of two numbers"` both of them should return false because there's exactly

9 question marks between this pair "**9**???1???9???**1**???9"

and

6 question marks between this pair "**5**??aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa?5?a??**5**"

Yet below solution, which also happened to have the most up votes, is correct even tho it doesn't meet the condition of "exactly 3 question marks between **every pair** of two numbers"
It only chkecks if number of question marks isn't less than 3 but should also return false if it's more than 3.

```
function QuestionsMarks(str) { 
    res = false;
    for(let i=0; i<str.length; i++){
        for(let j=i+1; j<str.length; j++){
            if(Number(str[i]) + Number(str[j])=== 10){
                res = true;
                if(str.slice(i,j).split("?").length -1 < 3){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

How so ?

Comment: In the problem statement, it's told that 
> For example:  "arrb6???4xxbl5???eee5" => return true because there are exactly 3 question marks between 6 and 4, and 3 question marks between 5 and 5 at the end of the string.

Comment: So it just means for nearest pair of numbers

Comment: @DhanaD. Yes that specific string meets the condition so it returns true.
Wheras this one "5??aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa?5?a??5" doesn't yet as per the Coderbyte it returns true even tho there isn't "exactly 3 question marks between EVERY two numbers"

Comment: why do you think **5??aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa?5?a??5** is false? @mdjpgarrett

Comment: Between first and 2nd `5`, there are 3 `?` and between 2nd `5` and 3rd `5`, there are also 3 `?`

Comment: @Dhana D It says it right there in my question but I’ll tell once again. 
It should return false because there’s 9 question marks between 1st 5 and the last 5. Still a pair isn’t it ?

Comment: I don't think this can be answered without input from Coderbyte. The problem boils down to *what is a pair of numbers*? You seem to interpret it as "every possible two numbers in the string", Coderbyte seems to interpret as "every possible two numbers in the string, **without** other numbers in between". You wrote your code for your interpretation.

Comment: Side note: Please! scope your variables to your function. Meaning `let result = false;` instead of `result = false;`!

Comment: @Yoshi Noted. Yup sounds about right, I’d have to write to Codebyte directly I guess. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score -1):

This answer actually works. When you loop through the array of string of length greater than 4. You need to determine whether the current value in the index is Numeric or not. You also need to keep track of whether any contigous value in the string is '?' for three consecutive interval.

```
//check whether a value is numeric or not
function isNumeric(n) {
   return !isNaN(parseInt(n));
}

// check whether any pair of number between ??? sum up to 10 
// if it does not exist return false if it exist return true
function questionMarks(s) {
  // at least the length of string should be 5
  if(s.length < 5) {
    return false
  }
  let countOfQuestionMark = 0
  let currentNumber
  let previousNumber
  let status = false
  for(let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    num = isNumeric(s[i])
    if(num) {
      //keep track of the question marks
      if(countOfQuestionMark === 3) {
        //get possible number before the index Of First Question Mark
        let possibleNumber = s[i - 4]
        if(isNumeric(possibleNumber)) {
          previousNumber = parseInt(possibleNumber)
          currentNumber = parseInt(s[i])
          sum = previousNumber + currentNumber
          if(sum == 10) {
            status = true
            break
          } else {
            countOfQuestionMark = 0
          }
        }
      } else {
        countOfNumber = 0
        continue
      }
    } else {
      if(s[i] === '?') {
        if(s[i - 1] === '?') {
          countOfQuestionMark += 1
        } else {
          countOfQuestionMark = 1
        }
        continue
      } else {
        countOfQuestionMark = 0
      }
    }
  }
  return status
}

console.log(questionMarks('1??8???1')) returns true
```

You can check it out here
https://replit.com/join/ahphohjgqj-abubakriolaitan

Comment: Not my dv, but how is a block of code without any annotations helpful here?

Comment: Thanks but I wasn't looking for the answer that works as I have included it in the original post myself.

Question here is why the "correct answer" is marked as correct when it doesn't do the job.

Comment: I posted this answer because looking at your code it will take O(n2) time compared to mine that will take O(n) time.

Comment: Again, not what I was asking for.